# How to include external "lib" directory in multi-project .vstemplate?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-templates

I've written a multi-project .vstemplate file, which works alright, except that the projects have some external dependencies (.dll's) that I want to include with the template, as a peer directory to all the project directories, such that the generated solution looks like:

```
slndir
    lib # dependencies
    proj1
    proj2
```

I have everything except lib.  Is there any way to generate this directory and deploy files into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no built-in way to create/add a folder directly under the solution.

However, vstemplate engine is extensible; If you implement the [IWizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/microsoft.visualstudio.templatewizard.iwizard%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) interface you'll be abble to add any custom logic you want.

Check out Craig Skibo's answer on this [MSDN forum question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/d7407d60-96e3-429a-84ef-be4cb8edcf95) for the details on using the DTE automation API from your IWizard.RunFinished method to add a solution item.